# Making a Coefficient Plot from Different Models

Tags: r, plot

I have a question of making a coefficient plot. How can I make a coefficient plot which coefficients come from different kinds of models? For example

```
 > med.out1$d.avg
 [1] 0.03856374
 > med.out1$d.avg.ci
    2.5%      97.5% 
 0.02406029 0.05213770 
 > med.out2$d.avg
 [1] 0.03703407
> med.out2$d.avg.ci
  2.5%      97.5% 
0.02320818 0.05294310 
> med.out3$d.avg
[1] 0.03631961
> med.out3$d.avg.ci
  2.5%      97.5% 
0.02158095 0.05110621
```

With these estimates, how can make a plot with all of these three coefficients together? Basic plot program, ggplot, or any recommended coefficient plot program are all good for me.

Thank you.

Comment: depending on the model types, `arm::coefplot` or the `coefplot` package (github?) or the `coefplot2` package (R-forge/`http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R`) -- but these depend on knowing the model type (S3 methods)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is newly released package, so I need a manual way to put the result together.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have a more easily reproducible question, but something like:

```
mList <- list(med.out1,med.out2,med.out3)
est <- sapply(mList,"[[","d.avg")
lwr <- sapply(mList,function(x) x$d.avg.ci[1])
upr <- sapply(mList,function(x) x$d.avg.ci[2])
library(plotrix)
plotCI(1:3,est,ui=upr,li=lwr,axes=FALSE)
axis(side=2)
axis(side=1,at=1:3,labels=c("med.out1","med.out2","med.out3"))
```